# Display Bitcoin value with JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, bitcoin

Any idea why the Bitcoin value is at 0?

I'm retrieving the data with json:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "https://bitpay.com/api/rates",
    success: function( data ) { ... }
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wL5jh7np/

Comment: Because `num` is 0, so `0 / 380.41 = 0`, what is `num` and what are you trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is right here:  `var tex = jQuery(this).text(); //this is empty!`
then you go off and do this `var num = Number(tex.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));//now num=0`
and then you do this ...

```
text: ""+(num/data[member].rate).toFixed(4)+" BTC*" //0 times something ... always 0;
```

so to fix this problem you will have to make sure that the value you read is actually meaningful ...

http://jsfiddle.net/wL5jh7np/7/

Comment: Hi Birgit! I've attempted to take this a step further: http://jsfiddle.net/askhflajsf/ywx6L9zn/4/ -- but would you happen to know why the USD goes haywire when you type in 2 BTC?

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle is good. enter some number value in `span.pricedisplay' then you can see the result

The reason to see result as 0 (by default) is the `span.pricedisplay` has no value. and if we see the below calculation `num/data[member].rate` its very clear that num=0 for empty text and its result would be 0.

```
        // Read original text from span.pricedisplay and this referes to that span
        var tex = jQuery(this).text();

        // Convert text to a double
        var num = Number(tex.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));

        // Create a new div with the class BTC_Price and append it after the original price
        var n = jQuery('<div/>', {
            class: 'BTC_Price',
            text: ""+(num/data[member].rate).toFixed(4)+" BTC*"
        }).insertAfter(jQuery(this));
```